# Store a checked checkbox from a form in a session

Tags: php, session, checkbox

i want to store a checkbox value in a session if a user cheked the box. If so, the box should be checked after reload the page, too. If a user uncheck the box, the session should be destroyed and the box must be unchecked. Default is uncheked.

I tried different codes, but nothing will work. On my example the chekbox is always checked, even if the user cheked it or not.

Thank you so much!

My php:

```
session_start();

if( !empty($_POST['debug_on']) ) {
    $_SESSION['debug'] = true;
} else {
    $_SESSION['debug'] = false;

}
```

My form:

```
<form class="form-inline" name="form" method="post" action="">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Email</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
    <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="name@mail.com" value="<?= $email ?>" required >
  </div>
</div>

<div id="debugbox">
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="debug_on" id="debugbox" value="1" <?php if($_SESSION['debug'] = true); echo "checked='checked'"; ?>>
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Output debug</span>
  </label>
 </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
<br>
<br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this line : `echo "checked='checked'"` which should be `echo 'checked="checked"'`, but I'm proposing a whole solution if it pleases you.

Try this :

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['debug_on'])) {
    $_SESSION['debug'] = true;
} 
else {
    $_SESSION['debug'] = false;
}
```

And then in your HTML :

```
<?php print !empty($_SESSION['debug']) && $_SESSION['debug'] == true ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
```

Comment: Same here, after reload the checked box is unchecked :(

Comment: @Ronny well it's because we delete the session when the form is not posted!

Comment: its working as long as you dont check the box. If you check the box and after submit you uncheck it, it stays checked. I think the cookie is not empty after uncheck.

Comment: You mean after uncheck, you submit the form ? right ? I updated my answer once again

Comment: teeyo,that works now. the last thing: how can i store the session in a cookie to have the checkbox cheked after refresh the page?

Comment: You mean you check the box, but you don't submit the form, and you reload the page, you want the box to stay checked ? if that's the case you need to use **Ajax** on checkbox *change* action.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $refresh = "ok";
        if(!empty($_POST['email'])) 
        {
            $refresh ="";
        } 

<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="debug_on" id="debugbox" value="1" <?php if((isset($_SESSION['debug']) && $_SESSION['debug'] == true) || (!empty($refresh)) ) { echo "checked"; } ?> >
```

Comment: Thanks, Subhash. It works so far, but after reload the page the box is still uncheked. I want to store the chekded box after refresh. Thx!

Comment: Just check any random variable and make it empty when you used the post. and check empty on same line

Comment: Now the box is always checked, even if i uncheck or not